How to execute code for each element in a list?
I have what had ended up being a long block of code to do some calculations where I currently set the year in which I am interested manually. I am looking to do this instead using a list. Ideally, I would like to filter everything to the first element in the list, execute the code, then the next element etc. etc. and stack them all up at the end.
A completely oversimplified example would be:
list <- list(2021:2023)




Year
Count




2023
1


2023
3


2022
1


2022
1


2022
0


2021
1


2021
1


2021
3


2021
4



With the result



Year
Sum




2023
4


2022
2


2021
9



This is just a very basic example to give you an idea of what I am trying to do; the actual code is a long population mortality statistic calculation, so it's not as simple as simply aggregating as it appears in this example.
I am not even sure what this kind of thing would be called, so it is hard to search resources and examples I have found do not seem to fit my case. Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

aggregate(Count ~ Year, df, sum), if your dataframe is df

To take a list and apply something to its elements, you can lapply or any of several related functions like sapply, Map, purrr::map, dplyr::mutate (if the list is a dataframe column) ...

I have tried lapply, but I'm not sure that is the right one to use.  To clarify, I have created the code I wish to use (more-or-less) and it's a huge 97-line thing which draws in other sources of information - I just want to know how to split it up and filter on each element.  It's not as simple as putting a function in lapply.

Using dplyr verbs, I think that you are looking for group_by() and summarize(). The first allows you to group over multiple variables (e.g., year, cause of death, gender, age, etc.) that might be used, for example, in a life table while the latter allows you to calculate values using any formula down the rows in each group. Another alternative might be to look for packages that already do some of these things.
